# Deriving the Bleaney-Bowers equation from statistical mechanics

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

I've been recently reading about the derivation of the Bleaney-Bowers equation from Van Vleck paramagnetism and I am looking forward to derive it but using a statistical mechanics formalism instead.

The Bleaney-Bowers equation for the magnetic susceptibility is:

$$\chi = \frac{2ng_S\mu_B^2}{k_BT(3+e^{\Delta/k_BT})}$$

Now, in order to apply the statistical mechanics formalism, I've come up with the following system: N independent systems that do not interact with each other made by two spin-1/2 electrons that interact between themselves. As a result, there is a triplet state (S=1) and a single state (S=0), separated by a energy gap $\Delta$.

This is kind of a Heisenberg interaction whose hamiltonian per pair is:

$$\hat{h_1} = K ·\hat{\vec{S^a}}·\hat{\vec{S^b}}$$

Where $\hat{\vec{S^a}}$ and $\hat{\vec{S^b}}$ are the spin operators (4x4 spin matrices) for each particle and K is a positive constant. I've assumed that because it must have units of energy, $K = g_S\mu_B B$, where $g_S$ is the Landé factor (L=0), $\mu_0$ is the Bohr magneton and B is the applied magnetic field, but I don't know if such an equality for K is at all correct. In matrix representation (I've taken $\hbar=1$),

$$\hat{\vec{S^a}}·\hat{\vec{S^b}}= \frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0       & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
    0       & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, the partition function for this hamiltonian is

$$Z_1 = Tr(e^{-\frac{\hat{h_1}}{k_BT}}) = 3e^{-\frac{K}{4k_BT}}+e^{\frac{3K}{4k_BT}}$$

Where I've made use of the eigenvalues of the matrix. From here on, my idea is to obtain the Helmholtz free energy $F = -Nk_BT\ln{Z_1}$ to later obtain the magnetic susceptibility: $\chi = -\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial B^2}$, but by doing that I arrive to the final expression:

$$\chi = \frac{3Ng_S^2\mu_B^2 e^{g_S\mu_BB/k_BT}}{k_BT(3+e^{g_S\mu_BB/k_BT})^2}$$

Which is not the Bleaney-Bowers equation. Do you know what further assumptions I should take? Or what is wrong in my approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made an incorrect assumption that $K = g_S\mu_B B$. In fact, $K$ is related to the energy gap $\Delta$, not the external magnetic field $B$. To simplify the notation, we consider a two-spin Hamiltonian of the form
$$ 
\hat{H}_2 = J \hat{\vec{S}_1}\hat{\vec{S}_2} - h(\hat{S}_1^z + \hat{S}_2^z),
$$
where $J$ and $h$ are measured in energy units and characterize the spin-spin interaction and the interaction with an external magnetic field. For two spins of $1/2$, the partition function is
$$
Z_2(\theta) = e^{\frac{3J}{4\theta}} + e^{-\frac{J}{4\theta}}\left(e^{\frac{h}{\theta}} + 1 + e^{-\frac{h}{\theta}} \right),
$$
where $\theta$ is the temperature in energy units. The mean $z$-projection of the total spin is
$$
\langle S^z \rangle = \theta\frac{\partial}{\partial h}\ln Z_2(\theta) = \frac{2\sinh(h/\theta)}{e^{\Delta/\theta} + 1 + 2\cosh(h/\theta)},
$$
where $\Delta = J$. The zero-field susceptibility of the two-spin system is
$$
\tilde{\chi} = \left. \frac{\partial \langle S^z \rangle}{\partial h}\right|_{h = 0} = \frac{2}{\theta(e^{\Delta/\theta} + 3)}.
$$
From this, it is easy to obtain a formula for quantities in the required units of measurement.

Comment: Many thanks. What are the definitions of $J$ and $h$ in terms of the other constants?

Comment: @user9867 $h$ is related to the applied magnetic field. I think, it is something like $h = g_S\mu_B B$ (I am not used to SI units, sorry). $J$ characterize the spin-spin interaction magnitude. Sometimes, $J$ is called "exchange integral".  I use it instead of $K$ in the Hamiltonian and it has same meaning.

Comment: @user9867 In this problem, regardless of the applied magnetic field, there is an interaction between two spins. The energy scale of this inter-spins interaction is equal to $J$.

Comment: Right, I see it now. Thanks again @Gec!